# The 'Location' Header is not working at all in PHP

Tags: php, redirect, header, location

I was working on a PHP code, and had `header('Location: '.$location, TRUE, 200);`, it did not redirect to `$location` (Value here was "https://thepiratebay.se/" ). I have listed all the headers present, Please help.

As you can see that the `Location` header was present but didn't redirect to. Why?

Browsers tested: Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari.

Headers were (As shown by Chrome):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 25 Aug 2012 15:10:54 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) PHP/5.4.4
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.4
Location: https://thepiratebay.se/
Content-Length: 5935
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: If the browser didn't redirect, it's not PHP's fault.  Obviously the `header()` call did its job just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mistake is the `200` response code.

Change this line:

```
header('Location: '.$location, TRUE, 200);
```

To be

```
header('Location: '.$location, TRUE, $code);
```

Where `$code` is either 301 or 302 (Moved permanently vs Moved temporarily).

Comment: This just worked!! But what I am confused about is that this worked earlier and now it just didn't worked. Anyways Thanks!

Comment: Well, if you skip the response code parameter at all, PHP automatically sends a 302 response code for `Location` headers.

Comment: Don't forget 307 and 308 as well (as of HTTP/1.1).